# jquery function only working once?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this function that is suppose to change the html of a span. It works the first time but anyclick after that it doesn't change anything. I know the query is working because the database is updating. Here's the code.

```
$('#availabilityicon').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/changeavailability.php",
            success: function(msg) {
                    if(msg === "available") {
                            var vailspan = $('span#avail').html('<a id="availabilityicon" href="#"><img align="center" width="16px" height="16px" src="images/available.png" /></a>');
                    }
                    else if(msg === "unavailable") {
                            var availspan = $('span#avail').html('<a id="availabilityicon" href="#"><img align="center" width="16px" height="16px" src="images/unavailable.png" /></a>');
                    }
            }
    });
});
```

here is the php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
include("dbcon.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT availability FROM user WHERE username='$user' ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$availability = $row['availability'];
if($availability == 'yes') { 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET availability='no' WHERE username='$user'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "unavailable"; 
}
elseif($availability == 'no' or $availability == "") { 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET availability='yes' WHERE username='$user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "available"; 
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a spelling mistake in your javascript, you've put `vailspan` where you probably meant to put `availspan` after the `if(msg === "available") {` line.

If it's not that, try changing the `click` event to a `live` one:

```
$('#availabilityicon').live('click', function() {
```

just in case your javascript is overwriting that the `#availabilityicon` icon element and failing to re-attach the event to the new one

Comment: The 'spelling mistake' doesn't matter at all - that var is just being set to the result of the jQuery selector so it'll be the span. But you got it when you pointed out that he was replacing the element with another one with the same id. +1

Comment: firebug is saying "Missing ) after argument list." after that change

Comment: You've added an extra opening `(` right before `function`...remove that and it will work

Answer (score 2):

The "availabiltyicon" you click is being replaced with another with the same name. You can try using .live() or you can read up on event delegation.

Comment: I changed $('#availabilityicon').click(function() { to $('#availabilityicon').live("click",(function() { but now firebug is saying "Missing ) after argument list." I've never used .live before so I've probly forgot something.